# How do Apache, PHP, and MySQL All Work Together?

Tags: web

This is something I am trying to grasp my head around.

Okay, so Apache simply servers files on a web server to clients. I fully understand that. But then if you install PHP, suddenly PHP code will be interpreted before those files are served by Apache. Then you install MySQL, and all of a sudden PHP can work directly with MySQL.

What is really done in the installation process that allows these three things to work so closely together? If Apache and PHP are separate programs, then how do they both work together on serving files?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing happens suddenly.

TO have `PHP` work with `Apache` on Windows, you need to add the following lines in `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:\php\php5apache2_2.dll"
PHPIniDir 'c:\php'
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

(This is just referring to my settings) and then restart Apache to start serving PHP requests.

`PHP` comes with `Mysql` extension to handle `MySQL requests`. These days we have `PDO/Mysqli` extension to (a) avoid SQL injection (b) handle requests more efficiently. However as i mentioned above nothing happens automatically, you have to uncomment following lines in `php.ini` to make any of these extensions work for you:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

(Again referring to my php.ini on windows).

Hope that helps.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

PHP is a server side programming language that handles HTTP requests. It is fully featured and offers alot of helpful functions. Try some tutorials and you'll quickly be ready to use it.

HTTP requests are:

1. GET - which allows you to read data from your where you are storing data. This is done commonly with a database(MySQL) query
2. POST - For posting user data, commonly from HTML forms. PHP allows you to access this global variable $_POST['example'] and store it in the data.

PHP basically allows you to Create, Read, Update, Destroy (CRUD) with Databases.

> What is really done in the installation process that allows these three things to work so closely together? If Apache and PHP are separate programs, then how do they both work together on serving files?

They work together because you allow them to. In your php script you must connect to a sql database before you are able to use that database. look up "mysqli_connect()" in php documentation. HTML pages call PHP scripts usually through a user input form. So that on submit you add to a database. But they must be on the same server and domain! the same locality of all programming still applies.

Comment: Thanks! But I already have a good understanding of what PHP is. I am more confused over how it works with Apache.

Comment: It basically speaks to the web sever before the page is served up, or when asked to from user input. It allows you to request from the database. Say you have a link. But not a static link. say a post. that post has an ID. well if you delete that post. where does the link go now? it goes to post with id 1. well now that post is gone...well with php you can store active posts in a database. so that when a user clicks a link it goes to the post with the  correlating information. It is a dynamic link. changes as need be. as opposed to a static link.PHP works with apache through HTTP verbs.GET/POST